# showDialog() is not working within an adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to bring up a dialog when an ImageView in my adapter is clicked. I have tried several things but have not gotten it to work. Right now, I am trying to use showDialog() like I would in an Activity but have had no luck. It can not find the showDialog() method.

Adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String[] mStringArray = new String[mData.size()];
        mStringArray = mData.toArray(mStringArray);
        final Integer recordID = Integer.parseInt(mStringArray[position]);
        Cursor res = mydb.getData(recordID);
        ImageView cancel = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.x);
        res.close(); // that's important too, otherwise you're gonna leak cursors

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activityContext.showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
                mydb.deleteSavedVideo(recordID);
                mData.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_ALERT:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activityContext);
                builder.setTitle("Remove Video");
                builder.setMessage("hkjh.");
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new CancelOnClickListener());
                builder.setNegativeButton("Remove", new deleteRow());
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

*Updated*

Adapter constructor

```
public SavedVideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> data, MySQLiteHelper database) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mData = data;
mydb = database;
activityContext = context;
```

}

Activity:

```
public void getSavedVideos() {
        mydb = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
        listView.setEmptyView(rootview.findViewById(R.id.noSavedVideosTextView));

        //Get IDs of all rows in the db
        ArrayList savedVideoIDs = mydb.getAllSavedVideo();

        mSavedVideoAdapter = new SavedVideoAdapter(getActivity(), savedVideoIDs, mydb);
        listView.setAdapter(mSavedVideoAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadVideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `onCreateDialog` inside your `Adapter` class. You need to add this method inside your `Activity` class inorder to access the `Activity context`.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();` and `dialog.show();`just `builder.show();` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, my problem is that I can never call showDialog(). I assume it is because I am calling it from an adapter instead of an activity or that I am not using the right context or something like that.

Comment: Keep a track of your activity when creating your adapter(local variable called mActivity for example), then when creating your adapter pass it the activity.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with the following call:

```
activityContext.showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
```

How are you getting the the `Context` from your main `Activity` in the `getView` method of your `Adapter`? In order to solve the issue, simply pass the `Context` form your main `Activity` to your `Adapter` and use said `Context` for your `Dialog`.

**EDIT**

I think the issue is that you are using `onCreateDialog` in your `Adapter`, which you cannot do since `onCreateDialog` belongs to the `Activity` class. Try placing `onCreateDialog` in your main `Activity` and then showing the `Dialog` in the `Adapter`.

Also, when you instantiate your `Adapter`, try using:

```
mSavedVideoAdapter = new SavedVideoAdapter(this, savedVideoIDs, mydb);
```

instead of...

```
mSavedVideoAdapter = new SavedVideoAdapter(getActivity(), savedVideoIDs, mydb);
```

Comment: I am setting activityContext in the adapter constructor. It is set to the activities context.

Comment: Updated initial post.